# laravel filtering data from relationated table

Tags: laravel, join

I'm trying to make a search in a table but i cant bring the data of the relationated table, i am using this code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    if($request){
        $query = trim($request->get('search'));


        $nota = Nota::where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%'. $query . '%')

        ->orWhere('descripcion', 'LIKE', '%'. $query . '%')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id','category_id')
        ->orderBy('id','asc')
        ->paginate(5);


        return view('notas.index',['notas'=> $nota,'search' => $query]);
    }


    $nombre = $request->get('buscar');

    $usuarioEmail =auth()->user()->email;
    $notas=Nota::where('usuario', $usuarioEmail);
    $notas=Nota::with('Category')->get();
    $notas=Nota::nombre($nombre)->with('Category')->get();

    return view('notas.index', compact("notas"));

    this give me this error: 

    Illuminate\Database\QueryException
```

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `notas` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `category_id` where `nombre` LIKE %% or `descripcion` LIKE %% order by `id` asc limit 5 offset 0)

Comment: Are you wanting to order by the `categories` id or the `notas` id? Also, why have you got `if ($request)`?

Comment: In this case use eloquent relationship instead of using join Lolz

Comment: i want to filter by the name of the category, but i only can filter by the columns of notes and category_id but no other columns in the table categories

Comment: if you want to use elequent use elequent relationships, you can't use join on elequent. insteade use `DB::table('notas')->where......` but if you insist to use model then you have to use elequent relationships and add function for that relationship. something like `Nota::where(...)->with('categories' => function ($q){...})->pagination...`